# Include jQuery using code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must include jQuery in a page using code:

```
if (typeof window.jQuery === "undefined") {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"><\/script>');
    if (typeof Prototype !== "undefined") {
        document.write('<script>jQuery.noConflict();<\/script>');
    }
}
```

But then if I try to use jQuery, Firebug logs "jQuery undefined".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //
});
```

but jquery is correctly loaded

[image: jQuery]

Comment: Yes.. it is in the head section

Comment: The code is in a external javascript file included with `<script>`

Comment: Are you using jQuery after it's loaded or before?

Comment: Please read [this](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) - these days document.write is really mad function, giving you unexpected results

Comment: After... see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pampurio97/B7dq2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest against using document.write, use dom manipulation.

```
if (typeof window.jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = function(){
        if (typeof Prototype !== "undefined") {
            jQuery.noConflict();
        }
    }
    script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALCDr/

Comment: I just tried and that doesn't work. I think as long he is getting script from external resource he need to use `window.onload` as in Rob answer

Comment: @Musa [checked, still not working..](http://codepad.org/iksxQImB). However it's nice that works to OP :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski the script needs time to load, that's why that's why the check for Prototype is in the onload function

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert('!');
  });
}
```

do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The way the HTML5 boilerplate does it is the most efficient way.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

This will check to see if jQuery has been defined yet (I.e loaded), or (if not) it will load write the script to the page :).